# Div not positioning correctly in Firefox 50.0 and IE 11

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a `div` that is not positioning itself correctly in Firefox and IE 11, although it is correctly positioned in Chrome and MS Edge.

I have tried adding `{clear: both}` and `{overflow: hidden}` as suggested in other posts, but had no luck.

I want the scroll mouse to be positioned at the bottom center of the screen, but it moves to the right.

I have created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz16h65m/) and you can see its positioning is off in Firefox and IE 11.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
  <div class="welcome">
  <h1>HELLO, WELCOME</h1>
  <br>
  <h2>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</h2>
  <p>"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</p>
  <br>
</div>

<div class="scroll-downs">
  <div class="mousey">
   <div class="scroller"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-fluid {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right: 15px
}
.container-fluid::after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both
}
.vertical-center {
   min-height: 100%;
  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */

  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.welcome {
  text-align: center;
}
.scroll-downs {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 37px;
  height: 55px;
}
.mousey {
  width: 37px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  height: 55px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  border-radius: 25px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.scroller {
  width: 3px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 25%;
  background-color: #666;
  animation-name: scroll;
  animation-duration: 2.2s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.15,.41,.69,.94);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  10% { transform: translateY(0); opacity: 1; }
  100% { transform: translateY(20px); opacity: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Please be sure to include the actual relevant code in your question, and not a link that is formatted as code. That's really inconvenient for readers of the question, and liable to link rot down the road.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: @Serlite Yeah I realised that and changed it straight away, First time posting so was unaware of correct format.

Comment: @cblakey No problem, as long as you know going forward. When you get the chance, be sure to periodically review the answers to your question to determine if they meet your needs. To accept an answer, click the checkmark under it - otherwise, comment/edit your question to further clarify the problem if it's not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem: you're trying to use `margin:auto` to center an absolutely-positioned element, which is fine - except you haven't specified any horizontal positioning values for it (`left`/`right`).

When using this technique to center an absolutely-positioned element, these values must be defined (usually a value of 0 will suffice), or you'll be at the mercy of the browser's default behaviours. So modify your declaration block to:

```css
.scroll-downs {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 37px;
    height: 55px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz16h65m/5/) to show the code in action. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much @Serlite.